# create multiple formulas using values in a vector with a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, formula

Is there a way to create multiple formulas using multiple values in a vector using a for loop in R?

I have a dataset with 16 columns and want to create a formula to run in a model for each individual column. I could just write out the formula 16 times, but is there a way to do this using a loop?

For example:

```
year = c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999)
apple = c(1,4,6,8,9,9,2,4,7,4)
orange = c(7,1,5,9,2,1,7,1,3,8)
banana = c(6,4,4,8,9,8,8,7,5,9)
lemon = c(8,3,3,3,2,5,6,7,9,4)
df = data.frame(year,apple,orange,banana,lemon)

df
```

```
fruit = c(apple, orange,banana, lemon)

for (i in fruit){
    assign(paste("formula", i, sep = "_"), fruit[i]~year)
}
```

with the goal of getting:

```
formula_apple
formula_orange
formula_banana
formula_lemon
```

which are assigned the values:

```
formula_apple <- apple~year
formula_orange <- orange~year
formula_banana <- banana~year
formula_lemon <- lemon~year
```

such that I could run:

```
plot(formula_apple)
```

to get a graph of "apple" by "year"

Is this possible to do with a loop, or at all? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which type of model are you trying to Run. if you want a linear model for example, just use `lm(cbind(apple, orange, banana, lemon)~year, your_data)` and this will run all the models for you

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to run a more complex glm with multiple effect modifiers, ns for year, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by more complex `glm`? Glm is glm.  What kind of glm? or are you running a multinomial regression model?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
fruit <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% "year"]
forms <- lapply(fruit, function(x) as.formula(paste(x , "~ year")))
```

You could change the names of the list so they can be accessed by the column name:

```
names(forms) <- fruit
```

Then the formula can be accessed from the list or you can use `lapply` with the list.

```
forms[["apple"]]
```

You can also type out the names of the columns if you have lots of other extraneous columns in your `data.frame` and use `lapply` as above:

```
fruit <- c("apple", "orange" , "banana", "lemon")
```

Depending on your goal, it may be easiest to do the regression or test in the function as well rather than just storing the formulas.